# multiple Alertdialog in one Onclick

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i'm using 2 alertdialogs in my code, and i'm trying to handle Onclick. As far as i can tell we can use only one Onclick for multiple alertdialogs but i don't know how to implement it.
This is how i created my two Alertdialogers

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this); 
        builder.setTitle("Attention!");
        builder.setMessage("Sorry, location is not determined. Please enable location providers");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
        builder.create().show();
```

The same think for my second Alertbuilder.

Comment: I don't have problem with creating the Alertdialogs. My question is how to implement only one Onclick for two or more Alertdialogs?

Comment: You need to have a variable that determines which alert you have inflated and thus which alert's buttons you are clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
private static final int ALERT_ONE = 1;
private static final int ALERT_TWO = 2;
private int currAlert;
```

Then when you are going to show your alert

```
// For alert one
currAlert = ALERT_ONE;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle("Alert 1!");
    builder.setMessage("This is my first alert");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
    builder.create().show();
```

Or

```
// For alert two
currAlert = ALERT_TWO;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle("Alert 2!");
    builder.setMessage("This is my second alert");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
    builder.create().show();
```

Then in your onClick method just do

```
switch(currAlert){
     case ALERT_ONE:
          //do stuff
          break;
     case ALERT_TWO:
          //do stuff
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle("Attention!");
    builder.setMessage("Sorry, location is not determined. Please enable location providers");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
    builder.create().show();
```